# MySQL / MariaDB does not rollback transaction

Tags: mysql, mariadb, create-table, rollback

I am trying to make a transaction and then rollback afterwards.

My code is the following:

```
SET autocommit = OFF;
START TRANSACTION;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;
CREATE TABLE Test (test INT);
ROLLBACK;
```

However, even though I call `ROLLBACK`, the table `Test` will still be created.

The tables use InnoDB. I am using MariaDB version 10.3.15.

Comment: Does the table exist prior to executing the transaction?

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html

> ... The CREATE TABLE statement in InnoDB is processed as a single transaction. This means that a ROLLBACK from the user does not undo CREATE TABLE statements the user made during that transaction.